# If $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |a_{n+1}-a_{n}| $ converges, then $a_n$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Please check the following calculations are correct. 
Let say sequence $a_n \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ or $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ ,  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} |a_{n+1}-a_{n}| $ converges. In other words, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n+1}-a_{n} $ converges absolutely. Then: $a_{n}$ converges.

Proof: It suffices to show that $a_n$ is a cauchy sequence, since both in $\mathbb{R}$ and in $\mathbb{C}$ this is equivalent to convergence. Then, let's say $\epsilon > 0 $, we know that there is a $n_0$ that for $p \geq q \geq n0$ , $$ \left[ \sum_{n=p}^{\infty} |a_{n+1}-a_{n}| - \sum_{n=q}^{\infty} |a_{n+1}-a_{n}| \right] = \left| \sum_{n=q}^{p} |a_{n+1}-a_{n}| \right| \leq \epsilon$$

Then, to prove $a_n$ a cauchy sequence, given a certain $\epsilon$ take the previously obtained $n_0$ and if $p \geq q \geq n_0 $, we know:
$$ | a_p-a_q| \leq \left| \sum_{n=q}^{p} |a_{n+1}-a_{n}| \right| \leq \epsilon $$

Comment: @AlgorithmsX I edited now, the question is, is this a correct proof?

Comment: Alternatively, one may use
$$
a_n=a_0+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}( a_{k+1}-a_{n}). 
$$

Comment: @OlivierOloa Ok, but... what's that useful for?